# sequence of events in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

what is the proper way of doing the following:

1. getting DATE as user input
2. running a query
3. generating a report that uses the query

this is the solution i was thinking:

1. have a form that takes user input
2. run the query
3. open the report

what is the correct way of doing this>?

Comment: Not enough information. What do you mean by "running a query"? What type of query? SELECT? INSERT? UPDATE? Obviously, #3 implies a SELECT (otherwise it can't be used in a report), but if so, then step #2 is redundant, as "running" a SELECT query by itself will not do anything to populate the report.

Comment: my new policy is +1 for every fenton comment i see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dissent from this approach, as I don't like tying reports to particular forms.

Instead, I use a dialog form (as here) that is opened in the OnOpen event of the report, and writes the Recordsource of the report.

If you want the report to be runnable without popping up the dialog, you can make it conditional on OpenArgs, or, say, if the Filter property is already set (which is what happens if you use DoCmd.OpenReport with a WHERE argument).

I like to make reports and dialogs as independent as possible, and often I'll use a standalone class module as a data storage structure, and check it in the OnOpen event. If the public variable for the relevant instance of the class module is Nothing, then just run the report, otherwise, pull the data from the properties of the class module instance and write the Recordsource.

In this way, you can have the dialog form and the report completely independent. Both need know nothing about each other, but both will be used with the class module (though the form doesn't need to know anything about the class module instance).

For more detail, just ask.

This is a complicated subject, and I've spent years working on it to make apps as maintainable as possible. Decoupling UI objects from each other is one of the things that makes for better re-usability, and, hence, better maintainability and extensibility.

(of course, you don't need to use class modules -- you could use user-defined types, or arrays or whatever, but I like the capability to have multiple instances of the same structure, which is the whole point of a class module)

Answer (score 2):

A query can reference a form filed as an input parameter, which can be used as the query for the results to the report.

- So have a form with a date user
  input.
- Place a button that would open the
  report.
- the report should make use of a
  query/embedded sql, that uses the
  field from the form as input.

Typically the report, when run without the form open, would request the value of the "form field".

So in general, you would create a Reports Form, that you can luanch reports from, which has the required fields for the reports.

Comment: @I__ Here is a sample query: PARAMETERS [Forms]!frmDate![txtStart] DateTime;
SELECT m.id, m.field2, m.date_field
FROM MyTable AS m
WHERE m.date_field >= [Forms]!frmDate![txtStart];

Comment: FWIW, I have found that you only need to define the control reference as a parameter if the value returned is used in the SELECT or VALUSE statement of an INSERT or in the SET statement of an UPDATE, and even then, it only matters if the control is Null. For SELECTs, I've not found it necessary.

Comment: Apparently the database engine expects a date type to compare with m.date_field.  So even if TypeName([Forms]!frmDate![txtStart].Value) = "String", the engine will accept a string representation of a valid date.  I didn't realize that.

Comment: It's the magic of the Access expression service. BTW, when I said it doesn't matter for SELECTs, I meant only if the expression is in the WHERE clause, not if it's in the SELECT statement itself. In that latter case, you need the parameter in order that Nulls be handled reliably.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a button on the form in which you build the query and open the report in preview mode (assuming they do not want to just automatically send it to the default printer) in the Click event procedure for the button.