# why was my report sent to the printer?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a button and in the click event i have this code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "All_Ones"
```

when i click it, for some reason the report starts to print! why is this?

Comment: Not a significant programming question. In fact, a bloody stupidly elementary question, and one which I strongly suspect the questioner knows the answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MS Access 2003, from [OpenReport Method [Access 2003 VBA Language Reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220304(office.11).aspx)

**acViewNormal (default) Prints the report immediately.**

From 2007 [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032(office.12).aspx) and [AcView Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225993(v=office.12).aspx)

**acViewNormal (Default) Normal view**

So the question is, which version are you using?

Comment: please help with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008376/sequence-of-events-in-access